# In Grails, how do I fetch a domain proxy instead of the full record

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am working with domains mapped to a legacy database that makes extensive use of db-level user groups to control grants to both tables and columns.  I am needing to map the following simplified association:

JailBooking {
  Integer id,
  String name,
  Case case
}

Case {
  Integer id,
  String causeNumber,
  String caseType,
  String someFlag,
  String someOtherFlag
}

Now, due to table / column permissions, we have a user group that has full rights to select/insert/update the full JailBooking table, but can only select the id and causeNumber fields in Case.  When trying to set a Case record on JailBooking, any attempt to do a read on Case results in an exception because the query to load Case calls for all columns in the domain.  To persist a JailBooking record, we really only need the ID column from Case.

I know that when lazy-fetching objects, an uninitialized proxy will often be returned containing only the domain's id field.  Is there a way to manually fetch this, or a similar object, that only tries to access the id column from the Case table, and is acceptable for persisting a JailBooking record?

If it affects the answer at all, I am working with Grails 2.5.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jailBookingEntity.caseId to access the id without initializing the proxy. You can use the "Id" suffix on every related entity to get the Id value.

If you need the proxy you can use Case.load(jailBookingEntity.caseId)